# How to extract number before a symbol in C++

Tags: c++, text-extraction

I have tried Googling but just can't find my answer.

I have a string "0-9". I want to extract the number before and after the dash and store it in a variable

```
e.g
string A = "0-9";
output:
min = 0
max = 9
```

I managed to get the number after dash but not before.

```
string str = "0-9";
string max = str.substr(str.find("-") + 1);
cout << max;
```

It should work for "10-20" also.

Comment: Why not use `std::regex`?

Comment: @JamesAdkison -- because it's overkill for a simple parse like this.

Comment: @PeteBecker I understand. Counterpoint, If this parser really needs to only work for numbers then that is extra logic that the parser will have to implement whereas the regex match expression could provide that guarantee.

Comment: @JamesAdkison _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."_ -  Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

`string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;`

```
string str = "0-9";
string min = str.substr(0, str.find("-"));
cout << min;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
     auto dashPos = A.find('-');
     auto before = A.substr(0,dashPos);
     auto after = A.substr(dashPos + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int min, max;
    std::string s = "0-9";
    sscanf(s.data(), "%d-%d", &min, &max);
    std::cout << min << ", " << max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find this operator very handy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, char const* s) {

        if (is.flags() & std::ios::skipws) {
                while (std::isspace(is.peek()))
                        is.ignore(1);

                while (std::isspace((unsigned char)* s))
                        ++s;
        }

        while (*s && is.peek() == *s) {
                is.ignore(1);
                ++s;
        }
        if (*s)
                is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
}
```

This lets you "read" a string literal from an input stream. In doing so, it reads  input from the stream and matches it against the literal you pass. If they don't match, it set the stream's failbit. If they do match, it consumes that matching data from the stream.

I think that sounds more complicated than it really is. In real use, you'd do something like this:

```
std::istringstream input{"10-29"};

int min;
int max;

input >> min >> "-" >> max; // min = 10, max=29
```

This also recognizes the stream's `skipws` flag. If that's set (which it usually is) it skips white space before trying to read the delimiter you've specified, so input like `1 - 20` would work as well.

Comment: Another major benefit of this is the ability to read something like `10 - 20 + 30` and get out many values with many delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like a `regex` solution to this one.  It's pretty simple and actually uses the `prefix` and `suffix` properties of the `match_results`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::string A = "0-9";
    std::cmatch cm;
    std::regex_search(A.c_str(), cm, std::regex("-"));
    int nums[2]{ std::stoi(cm.prefix()), std::stoi(cm.suffix()) };
    for (auto i : nums) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```